# Can't start Spyder after conda update due to python.app error

Tags: conda, spyder

After

```
conda update --all
```

I can't start spyder anymore. If I run *spyder* in the terminal I get the following error:

```
/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: /anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python: No such file or directory
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please run `conda install -f python.app` and try again.

Comment: Great, it works. You might want to write it as an answer so that I can approve it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem is solved by running the following command in Terminal.app

```
conda install -f python.app
```